# Image upload by Tinymce in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to apply this plugin http://justboil.me/ to add upload option in tinymce.It's working fine in raw php.But the problem in cakephp.Here in cakephp I keep the tinymce folder in cakephp js folder and tinymce all option working fine.After add justboil plugin I have get the image upload option but the problem is after image select image is not uploading in my uploads folder.I think here the problem in assigning path.Here I have open a upload folder in webroot, than I have assigned this path in config file by below code

```
$config['img_path'] = '/app/webroot/uploads'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

Here the screen shorts

[image]

after trying to upload image

[image]

after add image this is just loading after load some moment give me a massage page not found.

[image]

Have any solution ? or have there any easy solution for upload image in text editor in cakephp?

Comment: Can you supply more information from your error logs so we can see what's happening on the cakephp side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your config like as if your tinymce code in js/tinymce:

```
$config['img_path'] = '../../uploads';
```

and if your tinymce code is directly in js than edit as :

```
 $config['img_path'] = '../uploads';
```